# Trouble evaluating this definite integral, either directly or with indefinite + limits

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, evaluation, symbolic, assumptions, version-12

I have the function

$$
\Sigma(x) = \frac{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}(\left| R\right| -1)}{\left(R^2-1\right) \left(x^2-1\right)}+\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}{\sqrt{R^2 \left(1-x^2\right)}}\right)-\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)}{\left(1-x^2\right)^{3/2}}
$$

and need to compute the integral

$$
\overline{\Sigma}(x) =\frac{2}{x^2}\int_0^xx\Sigma(x')dx'
$$

for $0<x<1$. My Mathematica (12.0) seems to hang without end on trying to do the definite integral:

```
sigx = (-ArcTan[Sqrt[R^2 - x^2]/Sqrt[1 - x^2]] + ArcTan[Sqrt[R^2 - x^2]/Sqrt[R^2 (1 - x^2)]])/(1 - x^2)^(3/2) + Sqrt[R^2 - x^2][-1 + Sqrt[R^2]]/((-1 + R^2) (-1 + x^2))
int = Integrate[x*sigx, {x, 0, X}, Assumptions->{x<1 && x<= R && x>0}]
```

And also on trying to take the limit on the indefinite result:

```
intIndef = Integrate[x*sigx, x, Assumptions->{x<1 && x<= R}]
Limit[intIndef, x->0, Assumptions->{R > 0, R \[Element] Reals}]
```

Note that I'm using what I think are important assumptions that should help things along. Is this integrand truly just nasty, or am I missing a possible technique?

Comment: For the definite case I think the right assumption would be `0<X<1` (note capital x). That said, it still might hang.

Answer (score 2):

Answer revised for `Abs[R] > 1`

The code for `sigx` in the question contains a typo, `[-1 + Sqrt[R^2]]` instead of `(-1 + Sqrt[R^2])`.  With it fixed and `R > 1` chosen, consistent with the code in the question, the following returns an answer in just a few minutes for Version 12.1.1

```
Integrate[x*sigx, x, Assumptions -> 0 < x < 1 && R > 1];
int = Collect[Simplify[%, 0 < x < 1 && R > 1], ArcTanh[_], Simplify]
int0 = Simplify[int /. x -> 0, R > 1]

(* Sqrt[R^2 - x^2]/(1 + R) - 
   ArcTan[Sqrt[(-R^2 + x^2)/(-1 + x^2)]]/Sqrt[1 - x^2] + 
   ArcTan[Sqrt[(-R^2 + x^2)/(-1 + x^2)]/R]/Sqrt[1 - x^2] - 
   (2 (-1 + R) ArcTanh[Sqrt[(R^2 - x^2)/(-1 + R^2)]])/Sqrt[-1 + R^2] - 
   (Sqrt[2] ArcTanh[Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(R^2 - x^2)/(-1 + R^2)]])/Sqrt[-1 + R^2] + 
   ((1 + R^2) ArcTanh[Sqrt[((1 + R^2) (1 - x^2/R^2))/(-1 + R^2)]])/Sqrt[-1 + R^4] *)
(* Pi/4 + R/(1 + R) - ArcTan[R] - 
   (2 (-1 + R) ArcTanh[R/Sqrt[-1 + R^2]])/Sqrt[-1 + R^2] - 
   (Sqrt[2] ArcTanh[(Sqrt[2] R)/Sqrt[-1 + R^2]])/Sqrt[-1 + R^2] + 
   ((1 + R^2) ArcTanh[Sqrt[(1 + R^2)/(-1 + R^2)]])/Sqrt[-1 + R^4] *)
```

A sample plot, for `R = 2`, is

```
Plot[Chop[(int - int0) /. R -> 2], {x, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

As verification, numerical integration yields the same curve.

```
NDSolveValue[{s'[x] == x*sigx /. R -> 2, s[0] == 0}, s[x], {x, 0, 1}];
```

Incidentally, the corresponding definite integral,

```
Integrate[x*sigx, {x, 0, y}, Assumptions -> 0 < y < 1 && R > 1]
```

returns unevaluated after several minutes.

For large negative `R`, the corresponding code yields expressions too long to be reproduced here, but sample plots are identical to those for corresponding positive `R`, as are the numerical results.  (That the numerical results are the same is to be expected, because `R` appears only as `R^2` in `sigx`.)

Comment: To @bbgodfrey  You have taken over a typo from Anonymous in `sigx ` . Nearly at the end, he used square brackets instead of parentheses in `[-1 + Sqrt[R^2]]  ` . So sigx und consequently your `int ` , where this appears nearly at the end of it, make no sense.

Comment: @Akku14  Yes, I saw that about 30 minutes ago and am about to fix it.  Thanks.